# Synonyms [angular2-material] and [angular-material2]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Should the tags [angular2-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-material) and [angular-material2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material2) be synonyms?

Comment: Well, material is its own thing, why does there even need to be a tag like either of those? Why not tag questions with [angular][material] and similar?

Comment: @TinyGiant If material is a own thing, But what I mean is that there are two tags to refer to the same-> *Material Design in Angular 2 is a project* They are using the two tags for a specific angular question, And that, besides being confused and more in the case of angular eg: *angularjs2 angular angular2 angular4 ...* Maybe some of the followers of a tag are not of another tag, with the invonvenientes of this `|` **Why not tag questions with [angular][material] and similar?** Those tags are used, but for more specific questions are used the tags the previous "I think" sorry for my English

Comment: Angular Material is its own library, so this tag does describe a discrete programming topic: https://material.angular.io  I would vote to delete both of these and just use the angular-material tag.