# Error on the tag description

Tags: support, tags

I found that [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material) and [angular-material2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material2) tags have both the same description, which is, I am guessing, incorrect.

Angular-material tag states:

> DO NOT use this tag for AngularJS Material questions.

And angular-material2 tag states:

> Do not
>   use this tag for AngularJS Material, the implementation of Material
>   Design for the older AngularJS framework.

This leaves no choice for the Angular Material for AngularJS.
Should I correct, as I have that privilege, but I am afraid it will trigger many re-tags and this is new for me,  or should I bring this to the moderator attention (then how?)?

UPDATE:

As suggested by @surej, there is [angularjs-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-material) tag for AngularJS.  After a quick check, I saw that almost everybody uses [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material) tag for AngularJS. Now, I am more confused between this three tags.

Possible solutions would be:

1. Synonymize  [angular-material2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material2) and [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material);
2. Synonymize  [angularjs-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-material) and  [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material) tags. This should be followed by [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material) tag edit to remove 'DO NOT use this tag for AngularJS Material questions' phrase.

In both cases the downside would be leaving some misstagged questions.

There are 3711 questions for  [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material) vs 1064 for  [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material) vs 88 questions for  [angularjs-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-material) .

What is the proper way of managing this?

Comment: I found [tag:angularjs-material] for angular material for v1.. I think these two need to be synonymized

Comment: you can use the synonym-request tag in MSO to make a request. Check similar requests to see how its done. Also read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86020/how-do-i-suggest-a-tag-synonym

Comment: [angular-material](https://github.com/angular/material) is not [angular-material2](https://github.com/angular/material2). Your solution 2 is more accurate but i have no idea what the second sentence is trying to say.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349630/yet-more-angular-tag-madness-this-time-about-angular-material

Comment: Also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346111/3346612 , https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296857/3346612 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339879/3346612

Comment: I will start editing and moving question from `angular-material2` tag to `angular-material`. Anyone else wants to help out? @Vega?

Comment: @Vega i will edit tag documentation in a couple of days then we can gradually start retagging. Okey?

Comment: I also requested to make angular-material and angular-material2 synonyms. There is no action on that yet

Comment: Yes, i am thinking to remove angular-material2 tags. Lets see what others have to say about this. Here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357233/synonyms-for-angular-material-tag

Answer (score 6):

There are even more tags floating around:

[ngmaterial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngmaterial) and [angular2-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-material)

The AngularJS (1.x) Material library is officially referred to as *AngularJS Material*, while the second version of it is simply called *Angular Material*, which is in line with the naming of the Angular core library.

[angular2-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-material) is a tag synonym for [angular-material2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material2), whereas both of them shouldn't even exist in my opinion.

I already cleaned-up and removed the low frequented tags [angular-material4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material4) (there is not even a version 4 of angular material - yet) and [ng2-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng2-material) throughout the last weeks.

In my opinion, the only tags to be used should be either [angularjs-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-material) or [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material). Or for some edge cases both of them.

Unfortunately this creates the need to manually divide [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material)

Comment: It does seem like the [tag:angular-material] is the biggest issue, since it's been around since at least 2014 and has a significant blend. But since it's explicitly described as being for Angular only, and not AngularJS, doesn't that mean that [this entire list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs+angular-material) (questions tagged both `angularjs` and `angular-material`) are the ones that require retagging?

Is there any hope that we could get a bulk retag from a moderator of all the questions that match the query above, to [tag:angularjs-material])?

Comment: The next step would then be to propose [tag:angular-material] as the master for synonyms [tag:angular2-material] and [tag:angular-material2]. That doesn't seem to have been suggested yet.