# Synonyms for angular-material tag

Tags: discussion, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

Can we have a one tag for [**Angular Material**](https://material.angular.io/)?. Currently there are three tags (that I know of) which users are using to ask questions:

- [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material)  × **3765**
- [angular-material2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material2) × **1165**
- [angular2-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-material) × **173**

Wouldn't it make more sense to make [angular-material2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material2) & [angular2-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-material) synonyms of [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material) to remove all the confusions?

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346111/synonyms-angular2-material-and-angular-material2 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349630/yet-more-angular-tag-madness-this-time-about-angular-material also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356577/error-on-the-tag-description